# Xcode6.4 cannot create new CocoaTouch Class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

Every time I create a new CocoaTouch Class in this page and press `Next`
[image]

This appears.
[image]

This means

> There have been a crash. Do you want to report it to Apple?

Here is the detailed crash report: [crash report](https://gist.github.com/wddwycc/defd3445b21414b8e4a6)

Somebody else seen this problem? Is there any solution?

I have deleted Xcode and re-downloaded it from App-Store, but it doesn't work.

Ps. When I create a Swift file instead of a Cocoa Touch Class, there's no crash.

Comment: can you transfer your langauge / crash report into english

Comment: else r u confirm to created the cocoa touch class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the crash happens right after I press `Next`

Comment: see this link may be helps you https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-create-a-custom-class-in-xcode-6, all are fine then add your crash report in english it is easy to solve your issue

Comment: sry my friend , i seen in first time , i never seen just like message in before

Comment: There's good news and bad news.  The good news is that there is a new version of the Xcode - 7.0.  The bad news is that it (on my watch) crashes every couple minutes (when trying to debug Swift).  That said, 7.1 Beta 1 is much more stable, so as you appear to be starting a project, you could start with that.

Comment: @chrisco Actually, I am working on an update for a released app, so the situation is emergency for me....

Comment: Try rolling back the project version then, stash changes in your local repo to find a baseline that works again.

Comment: @chrisco this is a problem of my Xcode, not of my repo..

Comment: please translate it in english (the crash report )

Comment: @nurfarazi "a crash happens and do you want to report it to apple?"

Comment: @nurfarazi see my update, you can find the detailed crash report

Comment: is this happening only in this project ? did you try opening a new project and try same steps ? i think the problem happening on this particular project . this type of situation i normally create a new project and copy pa all the class and asset step by step . run the project after every step.

Comment: @nurfarazi I've tried, it happens all the time

Comment: Have you tried using a different name for your subclass? Other than `ViewController`?